# pandas with Sqlite3 no show the data in python

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

Sir this is my code
no error but did not show the result no data
I am using python3 with Pondas with sqlite3
My db name is test and my table name is test1

please guide me on how the pandas show the data

thank you in advance
regard's

python3 with pandas with sqlite3

see  my code

```
import sqlite3 
import pandas as pd 
import datetime
con = sqlite3.connect('C:/Program Files/sqlite/muhammad.db') 
data = pd.read_sql_query('Select * from muhammad1;', con) 
data.head()
```

Comment: If there is no exception, it probably means your table is empty.  Did  you open your database with [SQLiteBrowser](https://sqlitebrowser.org/dl/)?

Comment: You note: ...My db name is test and my table name is test1 .. and than you build a database named muhammad.db and query from table muhammad1 ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think your sqlite file is located in Windows machine, and it seems like the seperator in the path is wrong. It should be `\` rather than `/` as in linux and Mac OS.

Secondly, if your db file name is `test`, it should be included in the sqlite path and also, if your table name is `test1`, the select query should be `SELECT * FROM test1`

---

Try to make sure whether the path is right with

```py
import os

path = 'C:/Program Files/sqlite/muhammad.db'
if os.path.exists(path):
    data = pd.read_sql_query(...)
else:
    print('file does not exist')
```

and then, verify the query.

---

#### Additional suggestion

try the following code

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine  
path = 'C:/Program Files/sqlite/muhammad.db'
engine = create_engine(f"sqlite:///{path}")  
with engine.connect() as conn, conn.begin():  
    data = pd.read_sql_table("muhammad1", conn)
```

as stated in [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html)

Comment: Dear Sir as per your instructions the result is C:/Program Files/sqlite/muhammad.db
PS C:\Users\Administrator>

Comment: Dear Sir as per your instructions the result is "   C:/Program Files/sqlite/muhammad.db " is the right path also my table name is muhammad1 is also rith data = pd.read_sql_query('Select * from muhammad1', con) but not show the data    I user the DB Sqlite browser but that data save in csv file not save in view

Comment: pandas only supports SQLAlchemy connectable (engine/connection) or database string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 connection. Other DBAPI2 objects are not tested. Please consider using SQLAlchemy.

Comment: @badarQureshi, I've added more guide on the answer. Please check it.

Comment: thank you for your reply but dear now see the new error after use your code      PS C:\Users\Administrator> & C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe d:/MFA/pythonfile/forpandas.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\MFA\pythonfile\forpandas.py", line 15, in <module>
    data = pd.read_sql_table("muhammad1", conn)

Comment: File "d:\MFA\pythonfile\forpandas.py", line 15, in <module>
    data = pd.read_sql_table("muhammad1", conn)

Comment: new_values = astype_array(values, dtype, copy=copy)
    return arr.astype(dtype, copy=True)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\MFA\pythonfile\forpandas.py", line 15, in <module>
    data = pd.read_sql_table("muhammad1", conn)

Comment: @badarQureshi Could you post the error on the question with updating? It seems like there is a difference between the type of real and the type expected from pandas?

Answer (score 0):

First write something to your db, than query it. My table name is named *data*. I write the database named *NewDatabase.db* to the same directory as the python script. Does this work on your machine?

```
import sqlite3 
import pandas as pd 

con = sqlite3.connect('NewDatabase.db')

data = {"column_name" : ["a", "b", "c"], "column_name1" : ["1", "2", "3"] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print("DataFrame",df)

# Writen to sqlite for query
df.to_sql(name='data', con=con, if_exists='fail')

# Read from sqlite
sql_data = pd.read_sql_query('Select * from data;', con) 
sql_data.head()
print("Database", sql_data.head())
```